# Trying to use find_element(By.XPATH) and getting element not interactable error on list of FULL Xpaths

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a scraper that will go on the eia.gov website and scrape electricity rates.

This is my scrape function:

```
from listOfElements import pieces
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyperclip


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#We need a function that scrapes the eia.gov website for electricity rates..
def scrape1():
    for piece in pieces:
        try:
            driver.get('https://www.eia.gov/electricity/monthly/epm_table_grapher.php?t=epmt_5_06_a')
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, piece)
            #element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
            element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'c')
            text = pyperclip.paste()
            with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception while processing {piece} -> {e}')
```

This is my separate file (called listOfElements) that is a list of elements (XPATH's)

```
pieces = ['/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]',           #Maine Residential
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]',                     #Maine Commercial
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]',                     #Maine Industrial
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]',                     #Massachusetts Residential
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]',                     #Massachusetts Commercial
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[7]',                     #Massachusetts Industrial
'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[8]',]                    #Massachusetts Transportation
```

This is the error I am getting (partial stacktrace):

```
runfile('C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Price Grabber/priceGrabber.py', wdir='C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Price Grabber')
Reloaded modules: listOfElements
C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Price Grabber\priceGrabber.py:21: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
Exception while processing /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2] -> Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00C97413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C29F61+1941345]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B1C520+836896]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B448E3+1001699]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B43FBE+999358]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B6414C+1130828]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B3F974+981364]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B64364+1131364]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B74302+1196802]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B63F66+1130342]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B3E546+976198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B3F456+980054]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E49632+1727522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00EFBA4D+2457661]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D2EB81+569713]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D2DD76+566118]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C30B2B+1968939]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C35988+1989000]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C35A75+1989237]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C3ECB1+2026673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x776DFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C37A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C37A4E+238]

Exception while processing /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4] -> Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00C97413+2389011]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C29F61+1941345]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B1C520+836896]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B448E3+1001699]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B43FBE+999358]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you get the data, it is not necessary to simulate CTRL+C to get the data, what you had was enough. To get the data you use the text attribute of the driver object and that's it!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from listOfElements import pieces
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#import pyperclip


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#We need a function that scrapes the eia.gov website for electricity rates..
def scrape1():
    url= 'https://www.eia.gov/electricity/monthly/epm_table_grapher.php?t=epmt_5_06_a'
    data = []
    for piece in pieces:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, piece)
            #element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
            #element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'c')
            #text = element.text
            data.append(element.text)
            #with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
           #    f.write(text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception while processing {piece} -> {e}')

    output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

    for value in data:
        output_file.write(value)
        output_file.write(" ")
    output_file.close()

scrape1()
```